# Using passport.js social authentication behind a proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, webpack

We have a front running on port 4040 and a back runnign on 5050.

We setup a node.js server that handles social auth the same way it's done in the passport docs:

```
app.get('/api/login/facebook', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }
));

app.get('/api/login/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        failureRedirect: '/api/try_again',
        successRedirect : '/api/good_job'
}));
```

This works when browsing directly to the local backend port, i.e: `localhost:5050/api/login/facebook`.

However, after setting up a proxy from webpack with`http-proxy`, and logging in with the frontend address `localhost:4040/api/login/facebook` it breaks and enters an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

We are using vuepack the proxy was setup incorrectly (don't remember how).
After changing the `server.js` file and proxying like this:

```
app.use('/api', proxy('http://arena.app:3030/', {
  proxyReqPathResolver: function(req) {
    return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
  }
}));
```

It seems to work, using: `express-http-proxy`